# Limitations of Safari using webgl with Three.js

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, three.js

I am testing an app and I can see it perfectly in my Ipad but not in my Iphone even if I donwnloaded already the last version of IOS.

Ipad:

[image: Ipad image]

Iphone:

[image: Iphone image]

I am using a fresnel material. Is there a problem with safari and a fresnel material, or just with safari and webgl?

Maybe it happens because I have an Iphone 5c? Because I downloaded the chrome app for the Iphone and it has the same problem.

Is there something that I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: are your textures power of two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the size of the images that I am using as textures. I made them smaller and now it works correctly.